# How can I install Ultrastar Deluxe in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, package-management, ultrastar-deluxe

I'd like to install [Ultrastar Deluxe](http://ultrastardx.sourceforge.net/) in Ubuntu 13.04. However, the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+packages) only contains packages for Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04, 10.10 and 10.04.

Is there any way I can install Ultrastar Deluxe in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: You can use the instructions for the PPA for 12.10.

Comment: That doesn't work here. I'm getting a 404 error when trying to install from the PPA. And when I'm trying to install the `ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_i386.deb` package, I'm getting errors about unmet dependencies.

Comment: Following [these instructions](http://handytutorial.com/install-ultrastar-deluxe-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10/) didn't work either.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to wait for them to create a 13.04 version. What radu posted usually does work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully installed UltraStart on my notebook MSI U100.
Download the packages from https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+packages

I used first:  ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-svn-20120608-1_all.deb

then:          ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-svn-20120608-1_i386.deb

And not had problems. I hope it works for you too!

Greetings!
   Javier.

Comment: I had to install them both, and then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. After you have installed the ppa sources, go and modify them for which distribution you want (*quantal* for Ubuntu 12.10 version for example): press <kbd>Super</kbd> (windows button), write Software & Updates, open it, go to Other sources, select which ppa want to modify and press Modify.

Comment: So I should change `raring` to `quantal`, or the other way around?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is because  Ultrastar Deluxe is not yet released for 13.04 (Raring).

Comment: This doesn't work on my laptop: apt-get can't find the `ultrastar` package.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the easiest way to install Ultrastar Deluxe for all supported Ubuntu versions, including 15.10 is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tobydox/ultrastardx   
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ultrastar-deluxe
```

after staring it by running

```
ultrastardx
```

you can find the songs folder under your home directory

```
~/.ultrastardx/songs/
```